# Group elements in collections of arrays

Tags: php, collections, iteration, import-from-csv

I have this code, it fetches data from CSV file using splFileObject:

```
while(!$this->_file->eof()){
     $data[$i] = $this->_file->fgetcsv();
}
```

This is the result :

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "134550;651099595;3004050;1340.03;16/04/15"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "134333;651099594;3004051;1500.03;10/08/15"
  }
 [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "134550;651099595;3004050;1340.03;16/04/15"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "134333;651099594;3004051;1500.03;10/08/15"
  }
}
```

What I want to do , is to group the arrays by collections of 2 (or whatever) like this (e.g of count = 2):

```
 array(12) {
    [0] => 
    array(2){
          [0]=>
       array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(41) "134550;651099595;3004050;1340.03;16/04/15"
        }
           [1]=>
        array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(41) "134550;651099595;3004050;1340.03;16/04/15"
        }
    }
    [1] =>
    array(2){
          [0]=>
       array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(41) "134550;651099595;3004050;1340.03;16/04/15"
        }
           [1]=>
        array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(41) "134550;651099595;3004050;1340.03;16/04/15"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$data = array_chunk($data, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a try and feed you back +1